# Confusion About Area Distortion and Orientation of Ellipsoid

Tags: differential-geometry, solution-verification

Let $K = \{ (x,y,z) \mathbb{R}^3 | (\frac xa)^2 +(\frac yb)^2 +(\frac zc)^2 =1\}$ oriented by outward-pointing unit normal field. Consider $f(x,y,z) = ( \frac {ay}b, \frac{bz}c, \frac{cx}a)$, $f: K \mapsto K$. I am asked to show whether $f$ is orientation preserving or orientation reserving and for $a>b>c>0$, want to find maximal $|| df_p||$ (area distortion). Area distortion is defined as $$\frac{|df_p(v_1) \times df_p(v_2)|}{|v_1 \times v_2|},$$ where $v_1,v_2$ is a basis of $K$.

My attempt: $$df_p = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0& \frac ac \\ \frac ba & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \frac cb & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$, $\det(df_p)=1$ for every $p$. So it is orientation preserving, and since sign of determinant does not change with respect to basis we choose, it is orientation preserving. Furthermore since $df_p(v_1) \times df_p(v_2) = \det(df_p) ( v_1 \times v_2)$, the area distortion does not change so every $p \in K$ is maximal and minimal.

But I feel like there is something I am missing because I did not use outward-pointing unit normal field, and since area distortion is the same everywhere, there is no maximal. Is anything wrong with what I've done?

Comment: Yes, there's something wrong. You computed the derivative of the map on $\Bbb R^3$. You have to restrict to the tangent plane of the ellipsoid.

Comment: @TedShifrin i guess i got what you mean, but doesn't it put this in a form where it is almost imposible to work on? Do you have any hint on to make the computation easier? Also how does orientation come into play when we take coordinate charts?

Comment: The easiest way to look at orientation here is to see whether $df_p$, as you computed it, maps the outward-pointing normal to an outward-pointing or inward-pointing normal. I presume that assumption $a>b>c>0$ applies only to their second question.

Comment: @TedShifrin i think i'm completely lost because how do you even rigoriously define "outward" pointing normal vector? The book that I'm currently using doesn't have a definition for it

Comment: It means that it's pointing away from the interior of the region. So, for example, when $x>0$, the normal vector will have a positive $x$-coordinate.

Comment: @TedShifrin also for the  second part, since for every $p \in K$, we can find neighborhood $U$ of $p$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that there exists smooth function on U that agrees with our function $f$ on $U \cap K$, and I feel like what I did shows that for that extended function the matrix i wrote applies, so it should apply for our $f$. I feel like this argument should fix the issue in your first comment. Do you think anything is wrong with this one?

Comment: You still need to restrict your linear map on $\Bbb R^3$ to the tangent plane of the surface.

Comment: @TedShifrin so it is true that area distortion of $f$ is constant at every point? because this should not break the generality.

Comment: No, the distortion factor varies. Try calculating it at $(a,0,0)$ and at $(0,b,0)$, for example.

Comment: @TedShifrin i feel like i misunderstood everything. It doesnt make sense for me. The Jacobian is always constant isnt it (atleast in this case because it does not depend on variables )? Why area distortion should vary if it is constant?